# Import Error when trying to import NLTK module

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to implement a constituency parser from the below website.
https://bbengfort.github.io/snippets/2018/06/22/corenlp-nltk-parses.html

`from  nltk.parse.corenlpnltk.pa  import CoreNLPParser`

When I am trying the above step, I get this error.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from  nltk.parse.corenlpnltk.pa  import CoreNLPParser
ImportError: No module named corenlpnltk.pa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong import.

**Use this:**

```
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser
```

Ref: https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/corenlp.html